# With Rails Devise, allowing userid/password login concurrently with SAML

Tags: devise

We have an app that uses devise_saml_authenticatable.  We also need to allow a developer to login via userid and password in a form (because developers cannot get accounts on the enterprise directory.)  I'm assuming this is possible however I want to confirm this first and also ask if there is a best-practice for doing this.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently added a wiki page for the project to document this: https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/wiki/Supporting-multiple-authentication-strategies

Basically you'll need to add routes for both strategies, and implement the sign_out controller action yourself. Call the regular devise `sign_out` method, which is strategy-agnosti